# Why am I getting Media type unsupported 415 error?

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, tomcat, media-type

My web service Java class goes like this

```
@Path("/signUp")
public class SignUpService{
    (POST)
    @Path("/sendCode")
    @Consumes(Media_APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(Media_APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String signUp(Incoming streamingData){
       //some logic goes here
       return someString;
    }
   return someString;
}
```

//pardon with above code, I typed it based on what I could recollect.Real issue as follows

I have the server code running on Apache tomcat in my Mac and when I am sending a POST request with JSON body using POSTMAN and it works.

I have the same code deployed to tomcat in AWS Ubuntu, but I get Media Type unsupported 415 error. But GET requests are working fine in both my local machine and AWS deployment.

Comment: Try adding the [Request Dumper Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter), so you can see what headers are in the request.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. I didn't add

```
 @Consumes(Media_APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Produces(Media_APPLICATION_JSON)
```

on the class level.

Making the following change fixed the issue

```
@Path("/signUp")
@Consumes(Media_APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(Media_APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SignUpService{
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following dependency in pom.xml if using maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.2</version>
</dependency>
```

If not using maven, download the jar from here and add it to the classpath:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson/2.23.2

Also change (POST) to @POST.

Answer (score 0):

You no need to add the below annotation at class level to solve this problem.

`@Consumes(Media_APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Produces(Media_APPLICATION_JSON)`

You need to ensure the content-type which you are sending in the header with the request should match with the content type of `@consume` annotation of the jersey.